# EclipseLink: BatchFetch (BatchFetchType.IN) deep relationship fails using find or JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink (v2.3.2) bundled with GlassFish (v3.1.2.2) and I have experienced some problems using `@BatchFetch` (with `BatchFetchType.IN`).

I have 3 entities A, B, C:

```java
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    private String aId;

    @BatchFetch(value=BatchFetchType.IN)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<B> bs;

    public String getAId() {
        return aId;
    }

    public void setAId(String aId) {
        this.aId = aId;
    }

    public Collection<B> getBs() {
        return bs;
    }

    public void setBs(Collection<B> bs) {
        this.bs = bs;
    }
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    private String bId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
    private A a;

    @BatchFetch(value=BatchFetchType.IN)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "CID")
    private C c;

    public String getBId() {
        return bId;
    }

    public void setBId(String bId) {
        this.bId = bId;
    }

    public Root getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    private String cId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "c", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<B> parents = new ArrayList<B>();

    public String getCId() {
        return cId;
    }

    public void setCId(String cId) {
        this.cId = cId;
    }

    public Collection<B> getParents() {
        return parents;
    }

    public void setParents(Collection<B> parents) {
        this.parents = parents;
    }
}
```

Now I want to query for A and lazy load (using batch select) its Bs and also Cs.

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> query = builder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> root = query.from(A.class);
query.where(SOME CRITERIA FOR SEARCHING);
List<A> result = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
for (A a : result) {
    for (B b : a.getBs()) {
        C c = b.getC();
        // do something with c
    }
}
```

This works like a charm, BUT if I try to do following:

```java
A a = em.find(A.class, "SOME A ID");
for (B b : a.getBs()) {
    C c = b.getC(); // <---- QueryException is thrown
    // do something with c
}
```

It fails to fetch Cs with:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The parameter name [query-batch-parameter] in the query's selection criteria does not match any parameter name defined in the query.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="c" referenceClass=C sql="SELECT DISTINCT CID FROM C WHERE (CID IN ?))
```

Same problem occures if I'm using JPQL instead of CriteriaBuilder.

This behaviour applies to `BatchFetchType.IN`, using `BatchFetchType.EXISTS` functions well in all cases. I want to use IN cause it has some benefits compared to other fetch types.

Do I do something wrong, or is it possibly a bug in EclipeLink? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I haven't seen this issue, but you might want to try the latest EclipseLink version (2.5.1 I believe) to verify if its something that has been fixed.  If not, check the EclipseLink bug db http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Bugs and file one if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I've tried it with eclipselink 2.5.1 and it works! Seems to be a bug in the version we are using... Unfortunately we can't switch to newer version, so i will stick with `BatchFetchType.EXISTS`. Thanks for help :)